# Use the value of span class in if/else statement

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to get the value (AUD) and using it in the if statement below.

```
<span class="name" data-name="">AUD</span>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var currency = document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0]
    if (currency = AUD) {
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare the `currency` value to "AUD" in the conditional, you want to do `if (currency == "AUD")` (this is called a *loose* comparison) or `if (currency === "AUD")` (this is called a *strict* comparison).

Though you need to first get the `.innerText` of `currency`. Right now, `currency` is the first *node* that was found by `getElementsByClassName`. So change this to `var currency = document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerText` to get the text value of the node, and then you can do the conditional like above.

```js
function myFunction() {
  //check the first 'name' text
  var currency = document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerText;
  if (currency == "AUD") {
    console.log('currency is AUD');
  } else {
    console.log('currency is not AUD');
  }

  //check the second 'name' text
  var currency2 = document.getElementsByClassName("name")[1].innerText;
  if (currency2 == "AUD") {
    console.log('currency is AUD');
  } else {
    console.log('currency is not AUD, it is ' + currency2);
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<span class="name" data-name="">AUD</span>

<span class="name" data-name="">USD</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a for loop like this

```
var currency = document.getElementsByClassName("name");

for(var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) {
    if(currency[i].innerHTML == "AUD") {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var currency = document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML;
    if (currency == 'AUD'){
        console.log(true)
    }
}
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
And don't forget to call myFunction() to make it work.

```
<span class="name" data-name="">AUD</span>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        let currency = document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0];
        let value = currency.innerText;
        let AUD = 'AUD';

        if (value == AUD) {
            console.log('yes')
        }
    }

    myFunction();
</script>
```